# How does nesting null coalescing operator(??) work in PHP? Need step-by-step explanation of execution flow

Tags: php, nested, php-7, execution, null-coalescing-operator

I'm using **PHP 7.2.0**

I've understood the normal basic usage of **null coalescing operator(??)** but I'm not able to understand the execution flow and functionality of when null coalescing operator(??) is nested.

Please consider below code example and explain me the execution-flow in step-by-step manner.

```
<?php

$foo = null;
$bar = null;
$baz = 1;
$qux = 2;

echo $foo ?? $bar ?? $baz ?? $qux; // outputs 1

?>
```

Comment: The first entry that isn't empty will be echoed; $foo and $bar are both empty, but $baz isn't

Comment: The right term for that is [Associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity)

Comment: @MarkBaker The test is not for if they are empty but if they are literally null (unset), empty variables will get echoed from this example. It is not for nothing called the NULL coalescing operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your example becomes cleaner, if you add parens around the single steps of the null coalescing operator.

```
echo ($foo ?? ($bar ?? ($baz ?? $qux)));
```

Basically it's the same as executing from left to right.

The null coalescing operator is right associative. That means that operations are grouped from right to left. I.e, the expression `a ?? b ?? c` is evaluated as `a ?? (b ?? c)`.

Comment: You can do $_POST['var']??$_GET['var']??"default" conveniently.

Answer (score 1):

It works in similar manner as it works in its basic usage.

The execution flow will be as follows :

1. It checks `isset($foo)` it's not been set, it contains `NULL` so, go for `$bar`
2. It checks `isset($bar)` it's not been set, it's too contains `NULL` so, go for `$baz`
3. It checks `isset($baz)` it's been set, it contains the value `1` so, it gets printed and execution stops.

Answer (score 1):

You could translate the null coalescing operator in a series of if/elseif/else statements. From you example:

```php
echo $foo ?? $bar ?? $baz ?? $qux; // outputs 1
```

Translated into if/else statements:

```php
<?php
$foo = null;
$bar = null;
$baz = 1;
$qux = 2;

if (isset($foo)) {
   echo $foo;
}
else if (isset($bar)) {
   echo $bar;
}
else if (isset($baz)) {
   echo $baz;
} 
else { 
    echo $qux;
}
```

Personaly I use the null coalescing operator very sparingly and nesting it seems like a recipe for disaster.

The null coalescing operator (apart from having a really annoying name), does not improve the readability of your code. I don't think the few lines spared is worth the extra mental overhead it requires when reading your code. Or is worth having other people having trouble reading/comprehend your code. So be a nice programmer to your fellow programmers and use the null coalescing operator sparingly and **never** nest it.